# How to display all the columns after applying group by function in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv')
df
```

this is my data
[datafile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDxe4.png)

this is the code i have used

[got this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMsDQ.png)

how to get column 'price' after applying group by function
[result i expect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/toAMc.png)

please help me out..!!
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `idxmin` instead of `min` to locate the row where the weight is the minimum of the group:

```
df.loc[df.groupby(['object_name', 'type'])['weight'].idxmin()]
```